# Anchor Tags With AJAX / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, anchor, hyperlink

I am looking to a way to use images as links to new pages inside my web app.

I am using data-file anchor tags to keep the user inside the web app.

```
<a data-file="salt.html?v=1"><img src="assets/images/template/salt.jpg" width="125" height="125" /> </a>
```

These tags are inside:

```
<div class="products_content">
```

My code looks like this:

```
$('.products_content a').on('click', function(){  
    $('.products_content a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    changePage( $(this).attr('data-file') );
});
```

Any ideas? I have no idea why it isn't working. I have a similar set up for my navigation and it works fine. My navigation set up is as follows:

```
<nav>
    <a data-file="home.html?v=1">Home</a>
    <a data-file="about.html?v=1">About Us</a>
    <a data-file="services.html?v=1">Services</a>
    <a data-file="products.html?v=1">Products</a>
</nav>
```

And:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('nav a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    changePage( $(this).attr('data-file') );
});

$('nav a:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am in over my head.

Comment: Are you double, extra, super sure you have everything inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`?

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You've stated it doesn't work, but you haven't specified what exactly doesn't work. Is the click event not firing? Are `$(this)` or `$(this).attr('data-file')` undefined? Have you tried running `changePage('salt.html?v=1')` inside the click callback?

Comment: The click events are not firing. But the navigation version of the code works perfectly. How would I include the changePage('salt.html?v=1') inside the click callback?

Comment: If the click events are not firing, then `changePage` is probably not the main problem. Try putting a class directly on the anchors and attach the click event using that, to check if your selector is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuq4x/1/). Are any errors showing up in the console? Is your selector finding the `anchor`s to begin with? Is the click event even getting fired? Is the `changePage()` method being included in that page somewhere?

Comment: Hi G_M thank you so much for your response. I have been testing the page on an iPad as that is what it is built for, and nothing happens when I click on the pictures I have set up as links. There is no response whatsoever. The changePage() is in the attached .js doc. Does it need to be on the page somewhere? I am a major beginner at this stuff, and I am thankful for any help.

Comment: If the <div class="products_content"> is inside two other divs do they need to be included in the code?